# How to make a checkbox IE7 and IE8 compatible? (using jQuery)

Tags: html, forms, css, internet-explorer-7

IE8 Screenshot (Bug):
[image]

Google Chrome "Screenshot" (What it should look like):
[image]

The current checkbox has been styled using CSS3 is there any way to make it compatible?

The checkbox styling We've done in JSFiddle is a part of technique of CSS3 so lower browser cannot render some of it that's why. Please check the form on IE Tester (which you can download and test lower IE version, if using Windows) and you will see what I mean.

http://www.fratelliristorante.com.au/contact.html

http://jsfiddle.net/E5CxM/2/

```
<p>
<label></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" value="Yes" checked="checked">
<label for="checkbox" style="margin-right:10px;"></label>Subscribe me to your mailing list for upcoming events, hot offers and deals
</p>
```

*Note: We also used Dropkick (jQuery), which only styles select boxes but does not style checkbox.*

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because old IE doesn't support `:after`.

I have updated your HTML to use a hidden `<span>` to hold the checkmark, and adjusted the CSS to toggle its visibility.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E5CxM/11/)

Comment: this is still not checkable in IE7 or IE8. any other ideas although now it shows a weird tick.

Comment: @Josh:were you able to make it comptable to IE7 or IE8

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

now create css file named all-ie-only.css and put him the lite version to IE, because he bug.
you can use same to make different text box.

Comment: How does this help in any way?

Comment: the if IE is for IE browser only, means that you can add all tags / codes that in mozilla and chrome working but in IE not into there and make a liter version to that checkbox you've made.

Comment: Or you could just write code that works in all browsers, like in my answer. IE10 doesn't even support conditional comments anymore.

Comment: It not the same, if you try use grediant you see IE got different colors, he doesn't even make the grediant just the default background. ofc if the version is 10 so it will be work but if it 9 - 6 or less it wont work.

Comment: That's what Graceful Degradation is for. If people refuse to update their browsers, we shouldn't be expected to accomodate their poor judgement.

Comment: Maybe they do not know that there are new version and maybe they just dont know about the issues and bugs that old browsers got, or maybe they just too lazy to download / update new one, but your words wont change it. I do think that old browsers should be blocked for ever, but neither me can't change that. I hope we finish this disscution, Good night.

Comment: Internet Explorer is updated as part of Windows Update. There is literally no excuse there.

Comment: @Kolink: Of course there are excuses.  Windows XP won't run anything past IE 8.  ...and there is existing hardware that won't run anything past windows XP.  Also, there are many policies in corporate environments w.r.t. updates/upgrades.

Comment: @Gerrat That excuse falls apart when you can get a £100 laptop running Windows 8 (bought as an individual, not as part of a business). Sell your old hardware for cash, buy an upgrade, enjoy a richer online experience!

Comment: @Kolink:  "Laptop"..  Haha.  We use freezer-rated hardware in our coldstorage warehouse.  Your £100 laptop would last a couple days before needing to be replaced ...and that's just from temperature changes - never mind the abuse it would take from being attached to forklifts/lift trucks driving around the warehouse and onto tractor trailers.  Oh, and did I mention your £100 laptop needs a touchscreen?  We're not really that unique either.  Just pointing out that there are many environments where your simple "no excuse" falls apart.